# Family relation in Prolog

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I don't understand how to remove the infinite loop.When trying to find 
ancestors.

```
spouse(george,mel).
spouse(mel,george).
parent(george,elizabeth).
parent(george,margaret).
spouse(elizabeth,philip).
spouse(philip,elizabeth).
parent(elizabeth,charles).
parent(spencer,diana).
spouse(diana,charles).
spouse(charles,diana).

parent(X,Y):-spouse(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):-parent(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).
```

Prolog seems to go in an infinite loop due to the first rule. I would really like
to avoid hardcoding the facts like I had to for spouse(reflexive relation). But I can't seem to figure out how this problem is similar to other problems regarding transitive relations.

Comment: In Prolog, you don't want to have same facts / predicates separated by other named facts / predicates. I assume you saw the warning about discontiguous predicates or facts? Secondly, use a different name for your rule for `parents` versus your facts for `parents`. You definitely want to distinguish when making facts and rules like these.

Comment: Thank you for your second suggestion. It fixed my problem. If only this was mentioned explicitly in the online prolog [tutorial](http://lpn.swi-prolog.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse9).

Comment: The discontiguous predicates can cause a problem, too. Many Prologs will ignore later defined predicates if there are different ones defined in between.

Comment: Noted, I fixed the issue in my code.

Comment: Having the same functor for facts and rules is **required** for some situation. You should try to understand this aspect of **logic** to progress with your study.